# Show referenced documents details via mongoose REST?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I have a schema that has ref fields in it:

```
exports.metricSchema = new Schema({
    metricGroup: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'metricGroupSchema', required: true},
    metricType: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'metricTypeSchema', required: true},
    key: {unique: true, type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: String

});
```

I define and register them as:

```
var MetricGroupResource = apprest.resource = restful.model('MetricGroup', schemas.metricGroupSchema)
    .methods(defaultRestMethods);
MetricGroupResource.register(apprest, '/rest/metricgroup');
```

and it will show in mongoose REST as this:

```
{
"_id": "58a20f5f04ef5789d3ef8fb7",
"name": "Tangle Index",
"key": "TI",
"metricType": "58a20f43f1bbfe89c86bf602",
"metricGroup": "58a20f43f1bbfe89c86bf600",
"__v": 0
}
```

Is there a way to have mongoose show details of the referenced model without building custom populated views?

Comment: You mean something like "populate"?

Comment: Yes, similar to this, but without creating custom view for this

Comment: Well, the only wayt I can think of off the top of my head is to actually nest those extra documents into your model. And then figure out update strategy in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use populate function, you can read the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Example:

```
MyModel.find(query)
.populate(
    [
        {
            'path': 'metricGroup'
        },
        {
            'path': 'metricType'
        }
    ]
)
.exec(function (err, _array) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(_array); //print array with metricGroup and metricType fields with details
});
```

Comment: This will require a  custom view - is there a way to do this as part of default out of box model registration pattern? I updated my question to be little more specific on this.